# How to override styles in a react-chartist component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, chartist.js

I have a simple React JS component that wraps around the really cool react ChartistGraph component. The only issue is that the styling is seemingly overridden by the ChartistGraph default CSS. There is a lot of info on the regular [Chartist js package](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/) but not much on the [React JS package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartist).

As you can see, I'm trying to change the fill color two ways: through style classes and through a prop that supported on the component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Paper, withStyles } from 'material-ui';
import ChartistGraph from 'react-chartist';

const styles = theme => ({
  graphStyle: {
    fill: 'red',
  },
});

const CustomChart = ({ classes, graph }) => {
  return (
    <Paper>
      <ChartistGraph
        className={classes.graphStyle}
        data={graph.data}
        options={graph.options}
        type={graph.type}
        style={{ fill: 'red' }}
      />
    </Paper>
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CustomChart);
```

[A picture of the styles of the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/innab.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jss's nested rules (included by default in `material-ui`):

```
const styles = theme => ({
  graphStyle: {
    '& .ct-label': { fill: 'red' },
  },
});
```

Full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Paper, withStyles } from 'material-ui';
import ChartistGraph from 'react-chartist';

const styles = theme => ({
  graphStyle: {
    '& .ct-label': { fill: 'red' },
  },
});

const CustomChart = ({ classes, graph }) => {
  return (
    <Paper>
      <ChartistGraph
        className={classes.graphStyle}
        data={graph.data}
        options={graph.options}
        type={graph.type}
        // style={{ fill: 'red' }} // omitted
      />
    </Paper>
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CustomChart);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got into similar issue recently.React-Chartist is built on top of react not material-ui.When you inspect,you found regular css class names,not "material ui-ish" class-names(like MuiTable-root,MuiTable-selectedRow,etc).So ,imho,it won't support material-ui methods (withStyle/makeStyle) and rules.

But what you can do is:-

- create a css file and put your styles there
- And import it where you want

.You can import it on the main file of your app(index.js or whatever it is) since every css in your app will bundle in one file.